# How to get the section and sub-section a table belongs to?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code which loops through all the tables in a word document and pull all row and cell information. I also need to know which section and sub-section this table belongs too and record it in a cell in Excel. Can I access this information ?

```
 'On Error Resume Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim intChoice As Integer
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim objWord As Object
  Dim objdoc As Object
  Dim ChartObj As ChartObject
 'Dim objShape As InlineShape
  Dim tTable As Word.Table
  Dim wb As Worksheet
  Dim wb1 As Worksheet
  Set wb = Worksheets("Pull Images")
  Set wb1 = Worksheets("Results")
  wb1.Pictures.Delete
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  objWord.Visible = True
  Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
  intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
  'On Error Resume Next
  'if the user selects a file
  If intChoice <> 0 Then
  'get the path selected
  strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
  'opens the document
  Set objdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)
  With objWord.Documents(objdoc)
  Set Rng = wb.Range("A1")
  N = 3
  For Each tTable In objdoc.Tables
    tTable.Range.Copy
    Rng.Select
    Rng.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False
    With Rng.Resize(tTable.Rows.Count, tTable.Columns.Count)
        .Cells.UnMerge
        .Cells.ColumnWidth = 14
        .Cells.RowHeight = 14
        .Cells.Font.Size = 10
    End With

    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(tTable.Rows.Count + 2, 0)

 Next tTable
 End With
 End If
 'objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & 
  ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_MVR"
 'objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
  objWord.Quit
  Set objdoc = Nothing
  Set objWord = Nothing
  Set myrange = Nothing
  Set myrange1 = Nothing
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  end sub
```

Comment: [Yes, you can](http://vba.relief.jp/word-vba-get-current-section-number/).  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber), but it does not work.

Comment: `it does not work` is not a description of a problem

Comment: are you trying to get information about the `selection` object or about the `tTable` object ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the section number of each table in your document.

```
Dim Tbl As Table

With ActiveDocument
    For Each Tbl In .Tables
        Debug.Print Tbl.Range.Sections(1).Index
    Next Tbl
End With
```